# Draft answer posts

Tags: support, bug

Yesterday, I started writing a longish answer post, which I wasn't able to finish before I got kicked out of the college where I work. I wasn't too worried at the time, because I could see that there was a draft post there that seemed to be saved when I opened the post again on another computer.

However, when I got round to trying to finish it off this afternoon, it had disappeared! Aaaaargh. How long do drafts hang around for? How can I be sure if a draft post will still be there when I log on later? Is there any way for me to find my ghost post?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've had a little scour for similar questions, but couldn't find any. I've given this a 'bug' tag, but don't know if my disappearing draft is just part of the normal machinations of ELL.

Comment: This is strange--according to this [MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145100/draft-a-question), your draft shouldn't have disappeared. Hmm... Odd. Anyone else have any thoughts on this one?

Comment: I haven't specifically lost any drafts, but I have seen odd behavior when I use the site from my work place (I'm waiting for test results, not slacking!) I wrote it off as my work's proxy interfering. There is some sort of local to our network cache and they do some strange things to prevent credentials from getting saved (I have to log in to some websites at work multiple times where at home I don't). Maybe your college has a similar proxy/filtering set up?

Comment: @ColleenV Possibly, not sure (think I kind of understand - am a bit of an E-dunce) :) –

Comment: Whenever I find myself writing a long post, whether it's a question or an answer, I always make sure to save drafts in files on my own computer.  It's turned out to be helpful more than once!

Comment: Are you sure you went back to stack exchange in the same browser?  If you came back to it from a different browser that might have lost your draft.

Comment: @levininja Hmmm, that's a distinct possibility :)